# segmentation fault on pthread_mutex_init

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, pthreads

I'm trying to build a TCP/IP listener with a thread pool as workers.
The basic thing is not working, (cond_wait / cond_signal trouble) so I'm scaling down the problem. But with the code that follows I get a segmentation fault.

```
struct worker {
    pthread_t      tid;
    pthread_cond_t worker_cv;
    pthread_mutex_t worker_mutex;
    int worker_flag;
};

typedef struct worker worker_t; 

void initialize_flag( worker_t * w)
{
    printf( "Mutex (%d)\n", (int) sizeof w->worker_mutex );
    pthread_mutex_init (& w->worker_mutex, NULL);
    printf( "Cond (%d)\n", (int) sizeof w->worker_cv );
    pthread_cond_init (& w->worker_cv, NULL);
    printf( "Flag\n" );
    w->worker_flag = 0;
}
```

The SF occurs after the printf of "Mutex". 
The pointer I'm passing to initialize_flag() is a global one, and is malloc'ed in main(), to mimic the true behaviour I'm seeking.

TIA
((EDIT: taken from an answer of @marcelo):
Here is the relevant part of code you asked for

```
worker_t * worker;

main( )
{
    worker = malloc( sizeof( worker_t ) );

    if ( worker == NULL ) {
        fprintf( stderr, "malloc\n" );
        exit(1);
    }

    fprintf( stdout, "Zero\n" );

    memset( & worker, 0, sizeof( worker_t ) );

    fprintf( stdout, "Init\n" );

    initialize_flag( worker );
```

Comment: You might like to show the `malloc()`ing and calling code?

Comment: `"%zu"` would be the correct format to print `size_t`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code provokes undefined behaviour here by setting unallocated memory to zero:

> ```
> memset( & worker, 0, sizeof( worker_t ) );
> ```

The line above most probably mashes up the program's memory management, by writing `sizeof(worker_t)` bytes ***to the address*** of the the pointer to which `worker_t` bytes had been allocated, instead to where the pointer points to.

Doing so also overwrites the reference to the memory allocate. It is not accessable anymore, so cannot be `free()`ed anymore and the program leaks this memory.

To zero out the freshly allocated structure do:

```
memset(worker, 0, sizeof(worker_t ));
```

or

```
memset(worker, 0, sizeof(*worker));
```

or use `calloc()` to have it initialised to zero on allocation (no need to call `memset(worker, 0, ...)` anymore:

```
worker = calloc( 1, sizeof(worker_t));
```

or

```
worker = calloc( 1, sizeof(*worker));
```

---

As you might be wondering why the code not already crases here:

```
printf( "Mutex (%d)\n", (int) sizeof w->worker_mutex );
```

please be aware that the `sizeof(...)` expression as used above is calculated during compile time already as it is constant.

So the 1<sup>st</sup> time (the `NULL`-pointer) `w` is trying to be dereferenced is here:

```
pthread_mutex_init (& w->worker_mutex, NULL);
```

Doing so leads to the observed segmentation vilolation.

Comment: You are right: that memset() was inherited from a previous version of the program where worker was an automatic (stack) variable, so the & worker was correct. After moving worker to the global space and changing it to a pointer to be malloc'ed, I overlooked the '&'...

Answer (score 2):

I can't see anything wrong with the code, so I suppose this is likely to be because `w->worker` does not point a block of memory the size of pthread_mutex_t.

You don't show how `initialize_flag` is called, but it should be something like:

```
worker_t * w;
w = malloc(sizeof worker_t);
...
initialize_flag(w);
```

You say you've allocated this all in `main()`. Can I suggest you simply do:

```
worker_t test;
initialize_flag(&test);
```

to see whether that segfaults? Preferably without doing anything else in `main()`.

Also, I suggest you run in a debugger and print out `w->worker_mutex`, or make the first line of the function:

```
printf( "Mutex (%d:%p)\n", (int) sizeof w->worker_mutex, &(w->worker_mutex) );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
memset( & worker, 0, sizeof( worker_t ) ); // zero worker
```

is *not* the same thing as

```
memset( worker, 0, sizeof( worker_t ) ); // zero the objected worker designates
```

Your `memset` call is setting `worker` to `NULL` immediately before calling `initialize_flag`.

There's no need for dynamic allocation here at all, just allocate `worker` statically, it will be initially zeroed:

```
worker_t worker;

int main(void)
{
    fprintf( stdout, "Init\n" );
    initialize_flag( &worker );
```

Comment: Of course, I know that it's not the same to zero a pointer that to zero a memory area. But please, took the time to read that the SIGSEV was when initializing the mutex member of worker. Else, you waste time in futile comments. Thank you all.

Comment: @marcelo Yes it stands to reason that the segfault occurs the first time you dereference the NULL pointer you just made.

Comment: "*Your memset call is setting worker to NULL ...*" and it not only set `worker` to `0` but also `sizeof(*worker) - sizeof(worker)` bytes just following the memory where `worker` is stored.